# SSH Dynamic Port Forwarding

Tags: networking, ssh, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel, raspberry-pi

I've done lots of searching over the past couple of weeks.  And I've found a LOT of blog entries and articles on the subject.  But invariably they're either just an article talking about the benefits of using SSH and port forwarding or so poorly written that they're impossible to follow (and I don't mean that it's too much computer jargon).

I have a RasPi at home that is attached to my cable internet service.  It's got SSH enabled.

I've got a laptop that I take with me when I travel.  I've installed PuTTY on the laptop and have actually been using it to access the RasPi remotely to work on its configuration.

I've also taken care of letting the RasPi manage DynDNS so that when my IP address changes, the DNS A record is updated.

In PuTTY, I configured the SSH connection to route D80 traffic (Dynamic Port 80) to the RasPi.  I then configured IE to use localhost as the proxy.  But when I did, IE was unable to make a connection to ANY websites.

Is there something that I need to do on the RasPi to enable this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to explicitly configure IE to use that as a socks proxy. Try the instructions here: http://sockslist.net/articles/ie-internet-explorer-socks-proxy-how-to

Comment: I ended up going with OpenVPN.